# Should I install PWA offline caching at the start of the development?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

As the question suggests, should I install/add Progressive Web Application (PWA) offline caching at the start of the development, or should I only add it after development is complete? Because I've heard/read that installing it at the start may impact how we develop our application and how we connect with the backend. However, the part where I'm most confused is that the data is "cached" throughout the development, and I may not be able to get "fresh" data immediately unless I use incognito.

Comment: By Development, you mean the pages development? You can disable the service worker whenever you want to test development changes.

Comment: Thank you @RajeshG! I think that answered my question. I will search on this for whichever framework I'm using. Thanks again.